# Oauth and jmeter

Tags: oauth, jmeter

All:

I have an application that uses oauth as its authentication service and I am trying to use jmeter to load test general user experience flow (user creation, data searches etc..) I have no issues with the initial login because I am able to use the regular expression extractor to capture the POST parameters and pass the correct information for each unique user.

Where I am running into problems is when I try to script general page navigation after the login. Each page generates a unique "sig" value whenever it performs a GET or POST and I have know idea how to capture the unique "sig" so I do not run into user unauthorized to perform action type errors.

I'll admit I am not entirely sure what I'm talking about :) but I have been researching the subject and have come to the conclusion that I need some help. Here is an example of what I am trying to extract is:

https://${site}/Dispatcher?page=orgChooserEditor&element=enterButton&sig=b21hN2dKWk0yT3FMdklOQlYrd0czeXJ1MWpjPTtNV1F6TVRVeU56VXRPR0V6WVMwME1HWTNMV0V3T0RFdFl6Qm1Oell3TkRkbE1qVXc7cGFnZTtlbGVtZW50

The oauth signature method is RSA-SHA1 and oauth version is 1.0.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If each request needs to be signed with a different signature there is only one way to get `sig` parameter value for each request, it's combination of:

- [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)
- Any OAuth 1.0 Java client library, like:

  - [google-oauth-java-client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth/package-summary)
  - [oauth-signpost](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost)
- Groovy script which will retrieve access token using OAuth client library and store it into a JMeter Variable

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](http://How%20to%20Run%20Performance%20Tests%20on%20OAuth%20Secured%20Apps%20with%20JMeter) guide for more details

Comment: I'll give it a shot, do I need to to get the consumer key and consumer password from my development team?

Comment: Yes, it's something you should start with